# JavaScript button event handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning javascipt and now i have a piece of code but i am unable to get this to work, javascript isn't executed. I have already searched the web but i can't find an answer. Maybe you guys can help me with this.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text Game</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <button><span id="click">0</span></button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Variables
var waarde = {
  amount:2
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  updateValues();
});

function updateValues() {
  document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = waarde.amount;
}

$('#click').click(function() {
  waarde.amount = waarde.amount + 1;
  updateValues();
});
```

Comment: As a JavaScript developer, I love the title. :)

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: What do you mean by not working. Please specify. Also, always check your browser console while working with JS. For starters, there is no use of `$(document).ready(` if your `.click()` handler is outside.

Comment: Note that you are mixing vanilla JavaScript with jQuery. jQuery is a library that *extends* or *streamlines* JavaScript and makes it more crossbrowser friendly. In jQuery you can select an element by its ID like so: `$("#my-element")`, just like you have done in `$("#click").click()`. You can do the same in your `updateValues` function, namely: `$("#click").html(waarde.amount)`. (In this case you could even use the special keyword `this`, but if you're just learning you'll encounter that soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here:

**Issue #1:**

The element does not exist in the DOM to bind to yet, so do any or all of the following:

1. Move your `script` tag to the footer, right before the closing `</body>` tag (generally best practice anyway).
2. Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind to events on future elements.
3. Put all the JavaScript in the [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.

**Issue #2:**

You should not bind a click event handler on an element inside a `button`, it will not work in specification compliant browsers as the `button` consumes the event, and it not propagated to children.

See the [HTML5 spec for button](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) for reference:

> **Content model:**
>
> Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

Instead, bind the click event handler to the `button` itself.

```js
// Variables
var waarde = {
  amount: 2
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  updateValues();
});

function updateValues(){
  document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = waarde.amount;
}

// Binding to the button element using event delegation.
$(document).on('#button').click(function(){
  waarde.amount = waarde.amount + 1;
  updateValues();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button"><span id="click">0</span></button>
```

Also, unless you need the `span` element for something else, you could get rid of it and just use:

```
document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = waarde.amount;
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and example. Now I know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You should put this code:

```
$('#click').click(function(){
  waarde.amount = waarde.amount + 1;
  updateValues();
});
```

Inside of `$(document).ready(function(){})` function. `$('#click')` isn't in the DOM yet..

Answer (score 2):

You have to write "Click" event in document.ready

```
    var waarde = {
        amount: 2
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#click').click(function () {
            waarde.amount = waarde.amount + 1;
            updateValues();

        });
        updateValues();
    });

    function updateValues() {
        document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = waarde.amount;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you are not assigning an event handler when javascript loads the js file. It should be called in the ready function.

```
var waarde = {    
    amount:2    
};

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#click').click(function(){

        waarde.amount = waarde.amount + 1;    
        updateValues();    
    });

});

function updateValues(){    
    document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = waarde.amount;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap it inside the `ready` method!

```
    // Variables
    var waarde = {
      amount:2
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#click').click(function() {
        waarde.amount = waarde.amount + 1;
        updateValues();
      });
    });

   function updateValues() {
     document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = waarde.amount;
   }
```

Here's a codepen link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKXQza

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

You should put your jQuery event listener inside the document.ready.

There is no guarantee to work click event on span.

```js
// Variables
var waarde = {
amount:2
};

$(document).ready(function(){
updateValues();

$('#click2').click(function(){
waarde.amount++;
updateValues();
});

});

function updateValues(){
document.getElementById("click2").innerHTML = waarde.amount;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click2">0</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see your problem solution is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nnrfof8a/)

You are missing button click event in `$(document).ready(function(){}(;`